# Opening local folders in VS Code from WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL as my main command-line for all my git interactions.
I have the habit to open VS Code in the current folder by typing `code . &`

Recently VS Code started to open the folder as a remote folder instead of as a local folder.

The same thing happens even if I pass a full windows path like 
`code x:\\repos\\test`. Instead of opening the specified folder, a new empty file is opened at `./x:/repos/test`

Comment: Q: Windows 10 version? Does it work in previous VScode version? Where is VScode installed, in WSL or in Windows?

Comment: I have Windows 10 version 1903.
VSCode is installed as a normal windows application.
It worked before my vacation but not any more. Maybe something in the July update of VSCode.

Comment: This is probably because of the Windows 1903 update or update in code. Try this: `code.exe 'x:\repos\test'`. For current directory you can try `code.exe "$(wslpath -w "$(pwd)")"`

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Thank you. Trying to call `code.exe` failed. Also when using ordinary Cmd shell. This made me realize that is it a shell script called `code` in the path. When using Cmd, a script called `code.cmd` is used. Now I have something to dig into to find out what happens.